# Identifier 'runTimers' has already been declared

Tags: javascript, stackblitz

The program works perfectly on Visual Studio Code, but not sure Stackblitz. (I really need to use Stackblitz.)

The error message:

```
Identifier 'runTimers' has already been declared
```

The url Stackblitz is here => https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-yaoyey?file=index.html

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please include relevant code in the question itself, not linked to an external resource.  As for the error itself, it's telling you that you're declaring something called `runTimers` twice (at least) in the same scope.  You'd correct it by not doing that.  Either re-use the same variable or choose a new name for the new variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your codebase in `index.html`, you have two script tags as follow:

```html
<script src="btc.js"></script>
<script src="eth.js"></script>
```

Due to this, both `btc.js` and `eth.js` is imported and processed.

In `btc.js`, you have following at Line 25

```js
let runTimers = setInterval(
```

And in `eth.js`, you have following at Line 25

```js
let runTimers = setInterval(
```

So, the `runTimer` is declared twice, i.e. first `btc.js` is imported in `index.html` and the first `runTimer` variable is declared and cleared and after that `eth.js` is imported in `index.html` and it tries to create `runTimer`, which causes the error.

To fix this, simply rename the variables, which would avoid conflict and fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You declared a runTimers function in both eth.js and btc.js. You have access to any functions declared in a script file you loaded before the current one.